# Dynamically load array of objects to view them in a modal

Tags: php, ajax

A PHP function loops through an array of objects and lists down their titles. I have a link that opens a modal. How can I dynamically load the modal header and body with regard to the object $r from the $results when I press details?

```
<?php
foreach ($results as $r) {
?>

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>
                <?php echo $r['_source']['title']; ?></strong> <span id="showSearchTerm"></span></br>
            <a data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="MainNavText" id="MainNavHelp" href="#myModal">Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> -->
                    <h2 class="modal-title">
                        <?php echo $r['_source']['title']; ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $r['_source']['body']; ?>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <?php echo $r['_source']['path']['real']; ?>
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the information you need to fill up the modal from an Ajax call. After that you can add that content with:

```
$(".classname").append(information_from_Ajax_call_stored_in_variable);
```